# Leaflet: L.control.layers must click instead of mouseover

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a leaflet overlays, but it used mouseover. is there a way to make it clickable instead of mouseover that can be changed in js?

```
layers = new L.control.layers(null, overLays, {position: 'bottomright'}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Is it the layers control that you want to change, or the popups on the markers in the layer? Please share the code that creates the markers.

Answer (score 0):

Default is mouseover for desktop, onclick for mobile. Here you can find some explanations on how to achieve what you want:

- [Detailed expanation #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27233856/clickable-l-control-on-leaflet)
- [Detailed explanation #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46032224/leaflet-layer-control-open-only-on-click)